# How to set frequency limits when using acoustic_complexity_index() from scikit-maad?

Tags: analysis, soundscape, python, acoustic-indices

I have previously used R and the functions [ACI() from seewave](https://rdrr.io/cran/seewave/man/ACI.html) and [acoustic_complexity() from soundecology](https://ljvillanueva.github.io/soundecology/) to calculate the Acoustic Complexity Index (ACI). However, I am transitioning to using Python and is currently testing out [acoustic_complexity_index() from scikit-maad](https://scikit-maad.github.io/generated/maad.features.acoustic_complexity_index.html). The functions from both seewave and soundecology have arguments that can be used to set a maximum and/or minimum frequency to be used when calculating the index value, but it does not seem like scikit-maad has the same options (unless I am missing something).

Is there a way to use scikit-maad to calculate ACI over a specific frequency band? Alternatively, is there a different package/function in Python that would be better suited?